# coupon date falling on the same date as settlement date

Tags: vba, coupon

There is a coupon function in Excel that gives the date of the next coupon (coupncd) but which the date falls on the same days as the maturity (maturity is 15/02/2020 so the next coupon date should be 15/02/2019). However, what I want is the opposite since the date of the coupon falls on the same date as the date of settlement.

I tried to create this code but it's not working. I will be grateful for your help.

```
Function coupdate(settlement As Date, maturity As Date, frequency As Integer) As Date

Dim today As Date
Dim n As Integer
Dim newdate As Date
today = Now()
n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round((today - settlement) / 364, 0)
i = n
j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round((maturity - today) / 364, 0)
For i = n To j
newdate = DateAdd("m", ((i * 12) + frequency), settlement)
i = i + (frequency / 12)
Next i
coupdate = newdate

End Function
```

Comment: First basic question, what is this? `As Date` Second, what about it is not working?

Comment: function coupdate as date : it's for the function, it's going to be a date. As for what is not working I tried Msgbox i after for i=n to j and it doesn't show anything when I start the code, which means vba doesn't recognize j. so the problem is in for i= n to j

Comment: If the j variable is not working, it is likely because the maturity variable is not being passed to your function properly. For instance, a null variable of a date would likely give you 12:00AM, see if you can verify that the variable is passing correctly.

Comment: I checked and the j is correct for when I used msgbox right after j it showed the right one, so I don't get why it won't work in "For"